# How to apply environmental occlusion in ar.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, ar.js

I am just getting started with Ar.js and I am trying to implement environmental occlusion. But even after searching for quite some time now I haven't found any examples of tutorials on this topic in ar.js. All I could find was theoretical articles on occlusion but not any example on how to actually attain it.Can anyone point me in the right direction in this please?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no environmental occlusion in AR.js. Ar.js supports image/ marker tracking and geolocation targets.